# How to import the webform without changing the node id ?

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I am trying to import a webform from another drupal installation, but it was changing the node id of the webform. How can i preserve the node id of the webform ? Is there any module for importing without changing the node id

Answer (score 0):

There are no module allow you to do it, but if you want to transfer webform I suggest you to use [Webform share](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_share) module.

Also, if you just want to determinate webform by any unique id, you should use [UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) module.

Comment: Thanks for reply.With the UUID module can i preserve the nid of webform ?

Comment: You can use uuid in you code for loading webform node. Or you get nid by uuid.

Comment: Ok.. but i can't do any code changes because of client code base. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: If you realy need to create webform with the same nid, you can create it manually, by counting nids.

Comment: I tried but the newly creating node ids are already crossed the required id.

Comment: I think you lose this battle :(

Comment: Can i change the node id in database using any query ?

Comment: I think yes, but a lot of tables in db have a relation to node by nid, so you SHOULD NOT do it in prod database, it can broke the site.

Comment: First i will take dump to my local and then i will try

Comment: is there any query to update nid(node id) in all tables at a time

Comment: Think no, but you can try to use phpmyadmin to search all over database.